# How get static map from bing rest with mapArea?

Tags: rest, geolocation, bing-maps

I try to get a static map with "Bing REST" as explained in the microsoft documentation site. But for some unknow reason, the link i build didn't work ... :'(  And i really don't know why. I follow exactly the sample from Microsoft here:

[Get a Static Map](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701724.aspx)

**Get a map that shows a specified map area.**

http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Imagery/Map/imagerySet?mapArea=mapArea&mapSize=mapSize&pushpin=pushpin&mapLayer=mapLayer&format=format&mapMetadata=mapMetadata&key=BingMapsKey

Here is the link i build :

http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Imagery/Map/imagerySet?mapArea=45.219,-122.325,47.610,-122.107&mapSize=350,350&mapLayer=TrafficFlow&format=jpg&kebingKey

**Error code i get:**
--- "imagerySet: This parameter value has an invalid format." ---
[image]

If somebody can help me I will be grateful. Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't specified the type of image you want. You have to replace "imagerySet" with one of the following:

- Aerial - Aerial imagery.
- AerialWithLabels - Aerial imagery with a road overlay.
- Road – Roads without additional imagery.
- OrdnanceSurvey Ordnance Survey imagery. This imagery is visible only for the London area.

Comment: Thank you. That's the answer